# Using 'this' keyword in Java constructors

Tags: java, this

I am confused with the `this` keyword in Java. If a class has two constructors and we use the `this` keyword in some method, the object represented by `this` is instantiated using which of the two constructors?

Answer (score 26):

You have to distinguish between `this.` and `this()`, so to speak:

Most of the time, you use `this` as the reference to the current object, i.e. the reference of this object is replaced at runtime for `this`. For instance, if you use `this` as parameter or reference `this.someMember`.

You can have different constructors with different parameters, i.e. overload constructors. At the beginning of a constructor, you can call a different constructor by using `this(parameter_1, ... parameter_n);` as first instruction.

A nice explanation of both cases can be found at [the java tutorial about the this keyword](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html).

Answer (score 7):

It doesn't care and is indistinguishable

It is somewhat like building a car.
Depending on the features an other constructor is used,
but in the end you have a car (this)

Answer (score 6):

The `this` keyword has two meaning and the confusion could be around these two meanings.

In the constructor, `this(...)` is like a method call for constructors.  The compiler chooses which constructor to call based on the number and types of the arguments you use.

When you use `this` as a reference, it means this object, and which constructor was used is not important.

Answer (score 3):

You can think of the `this` keyword as a placeholder. At runtime that keyword is exchanged with the object reference of the object you are dealing with.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't have to do anything with constructors, memory allocation or anything like that. `this` keyword is just current object instance reference.

Answer (score 1):

Using `this` within a method body refers to the instance of the class in which the method exists.

This also implies that `this` cannot be used from a `static` context.

Answer (score 1):

`this` signifies the instance itself regarldless of how the instance was built

Answer (score 0):

1.'this' Keyword refers to object of class where it is used.Generally we write instance variable,constructors and methods in class.All this members are represented by 'this'.
2.When an object is created to a class,a default reference is also created internally to the object.It's nothing but 'this'.
3.Example for *this* keyword:
Sample(int x)//Parameterized Constructor{
this.x=x;//Stores local variable x into present class instance variable x
}